# ffmpeg - multiple output with thumbnails

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like ffmpeg to do the following:

- read an input mp4 *(-i movie.mp4)*
- skip the first 5 seconds *(-ss 5)*
- find scene changes and display the frame numbers *(-vf "select=gt(scene\, 0.4, showinfo))*
- output #1 - a gif file *(output.gif)*
- output #2 - a contact sheet with all the thumbnails *(-vf "select scale=320:-1, tile=12x200" thumbnails.png)*

This will generate the thumbnails:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i d:/Test/movie01.mp4 -ss 5 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4), showinfo, scale=320:-1, tile=12x200" -vsync 0 thumbnails%03d.png
```

this will generate the gif:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i d:/Test/movie01.mp4 -ss 5 -vf "select='not(mod(n,60))',setpts='N/(30*TB)', scale=320:-1" -vsync 0 output.gif
```

I would like to do both at once with 2 more features:

- set fps and resolution for the gif; I would like the gif to represent the whole movie in X seconds, at Y fps (I know the duration of the input movie so I can calculate how often a frame needs to be captured)
- set the width only for the thumbnail picture *(tile=12 for example)* and let ffmpeg determine the appropriate height

I have tried to compose a command line from what I read on this page: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs, using the split / map commands but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i input.mp4
-vf "select='not(mod(n,60))',setpts=N/Y/TB',scale=320:-1" -r Y output.gif
-vf "select='gt(scene\,0.4)',showinfo,scale=320:-1,tile=12x200" -vsync 0 thumbnails%03d.png
```

`tile` requires both W and H to be set.

Comment: ok, I didn't really understand that you could just chain outputs like that; that helps a lot! For the gif, how can I set things so that the gif will be X seconds and each of these seconds will have Y frames? for example I may want a 5 second gif with each second having 3 frames, condensing the whole movie in 15 frames.

Comment: The `60` should be replaced with this value: ` I can calculate how often a frame needs to be captured`

Comment: I understand that part, but how do I make sure my gif will have a specific number of frames per second? I have seen the -r option, the -fps option, and I'm not sure what are the differences

Comment: The setpts along with the `r` takes care of that. `r` is applied at the end and affects the output. The `fps` as a filter can be applied at any stage to a specific input. The current commands are fine.

Comment: oh, last question: in setpts=N/Y/TB, so Y is the number of total frames I want at the end, but what about N and TB?

Comment: I saw that N and TB are defined in the doc, but I get this error: Error initializing filter 'setpts' with args 'N/5/TB,scale=320:-1' (or N/Y/TB for that matter, although I didn't see Y defined anywhere)

Comment: ok, got it; there was a stray single quote in your sample that I hadn't caught. thanks!