# ffmpeg - same frame written multiple times?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(n,2000))',setpts=N/3/TB" -r 3 output.gif
```

I am writing 1 frame, every 2000, in a 3fps GIF file.

But when I look at ffmpeg's output there is something confusing:

```
speed=0.00997frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.01
speed=0.00498frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.01
speed=0.00332frame=    2 fps=0.6 q=-0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.34
speed=0.0847xframe=    2 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.34
speed=0.0678xframe=    2 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.34
speed=0.0565xframe=    2 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.34
speed=0.0968xframe=    3 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:00.68
speed=0.0847xframe=    3 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:00.68
speed=0.0753xframe=    3 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:00.68
speed=0.0678xframe=    4 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:01.01
speed=0.0915xframe=    4 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:01.01
speed=0.0839xframe=    4 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:01.01
speed=0.0774xframe=    4 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:01.01
speed=0.0954xframe=    5 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:01.34
speed=0.089x frame=    5 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:01.34
speed=0.0834xframe=    5 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:01.34
speed=0.0785xframe=    6 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.68
speed=0.093x frame=    6 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.68
speed=0.0881xframe=    6 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.68
speed=0.0837xframe=    6 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.68
```

It looks like each of the target frames is rebuilt multiple times.
I would expect something like this:

```
speed=0.00997frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.01
speed=0.00332frame=    2 fps=0.6 q=-0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.34
speed=0.0968xframe=    3 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:00.68
speed=0.0678xframe=    4 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=      41kB time=00:00:01.01
speed=0.0954xframe=    5 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:01.34
speed=0.0785xframe=    6 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.68
```

Am I missing something?

(this is a followup from [ffmpeg - multiple output with thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052216/ffmpeg-multiple-output-with-thumbnails))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the progress report. Each time it refreshes the report, if a new frame hasn't been encoded yet, it will display the same figure. A fps speed of `1.0` means 1 frame encoded each second. So, if there are two refreshes of the progress report in a second, the 2nd one will show the same frame count.

Comment: ok, I understand; so it doesn't process multiple source frame to update the destination frame then. Thanks!